# Library file issues when installing Gearman through Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, gearman

I have been installing Gearman job server on my WIN 7 machine through Cygwin terminal. I have extracted the tar file of gearman-1.1.12 successfully . Now I have to run ./configure to build the new makefile. But it says

```
   * CPP Flags:                  -fvisibility=hidden
   * LIBS:
   * LDFLAGS Flags:
   * Assertions enabled:        no
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * Building with libsqlite3   yes
   * Building with libdrizzle   yes
   * Building with libmemcached not found
   * Building with libpq        yes
   * Building with tokyocabinet no
   * Building with libmysql     yes
   * SSL enabled:               no
   * cyassl found:              no
   * openssl found:             yes
   * make -j:                   2
   * VCS checkout:              no
   * sphinx-build:              :

---
```

I tried to ignore and build the program by 'make' command, it gives:

```
/usr/bin/grep: /usr/lib/libintl.la: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libintl.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libintl.la' is not a valid libtool archive
Makefile:3707: recipe for target 'libgearman/libgearman.la' failed
make[1]: *** [libgearman/libgearman.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gearmand-1.1.12'
Makefile:3050: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to reinstall the Cygwin to customizely search the missing files but they were not present in the Cygwin libs. I am unable to fix this issue . Plz point me my mistake or guide me to any tutorial. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
wget github.com/fd00/yacp/archive/master.tar.gz
tar xf master.tar.gz yacp-master/gearmand
cd yacp-master/gearmand
cygport gearmand-1.1.12-1bl2.cygport download all
```

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani then you need to search for those missing tools on the web and install them, just like you're doing for Gearman.    There may be Cygwin packages, just check in the Cygwin setup program, or use apt-cyg.  You can also check the [Cygports project](http://cygwinports.org/) for the packages.  However, when you encounter an error, search for the _exact_ error and try to fix it yourself before coming here.  Show us you've done some work yourself.  From your questions, it doesn't look like you've put any effort into researching or fixing the issues before asking your questions.

Comment: @steven did u install other libs like tokyocabinet,cyassl, libmemcached during cygwin install or install them separately? Because i didnot find them during install . I tried by downloading them separately but during install it says as `Package cyassl not found or ambiguous name, exiting` on every package-installation

Comment: @Steven when I ran ./configure I came up with some files that were found missing (i.e tokyocabinet, cyassl, libmemcached). I dont know how you got away with them .

Comment: but before fix the 'make' command issues, I was wondering about how to deal with the missing files mentioned after running the './configure' . Didnot you install them ?

Comment: @Steven thanks for replying. I tried those but Im still getting same errors that I have mentioned with my question above.